# need to convert the data in another format

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

We have Data:

```
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5f87e152219aaf1f9404ef3f"),
    "parameterId": "5f914ca2679bae721d38410b",
    "average": 574998.153846154,
    "count": 26.0,
    "date": ISODate("2020-09-08T18:30:00.000Z"),
    "_class": "org.nec.iotplatform.entities.RawData"
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5f87e1e2219aaf1f9404eff5"),
    "parameterId": "5f914ca2679bae721d38410b",
    "average": 494217.606225681,
    "count": 1285.0,
    "date": ISODate("2020-09-09T18:30:00.000Z"),
    "_class": "org.nec.iotplatform.entities.RawData"
  }
]
```

I have query which I am executing on above data and then getting the result as below the query

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      "year": {
        "$year": "$date"
      },
      "month": {
        "$month": "$date"
      },
      "dayOfMonth": {
        "$dayOfMonth": "$date"
      },
      "average": "$average",
      "count": "$count",
      "Symbol": 1
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": {
        year: "$year",
        month: "$month",
        dayOfMonth: "$dayOfMonth"
      },
      "data": {
        "$push": "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "average": {
        "$divide": [
          {
            "$reduce": {
              "input": "$data",
              "initialValue": 0,
              "in": {
                "$add": [
                  "$$value",
                  {
                    "$multiply": [
                      "$$this.count",
                      "$$this.average"
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          },
          {
            $reduce: {
              input: "$data",
              initialValue: 0,
              in: {
                "$add": [
                  "$$value",
                  "$$this.count"
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

I am getting output :

```
 [{
        "_id" : {
            "year" : 2020,
            "month" : 9,
            "dayOfMonth" : 8
        },
        "average" : 574998.153846154
    },
    
    {
        "_id" : {
            "year" : 2020,
            "month" : 9,
            "dayOfMonth" : 9
        },
        "average" : 494217.606225681
    }]
```

But I need to format the result data like this. by adding the date like this:

```json
{
  2020-09-08T18:30:00.000Z :  574998.153846154,
  2020-09-09T18:30:00.000Z   :  494217.606225681
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`$dateFromString`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateFromString/) to create the date you want.

Also, you need `$concat` and `$toString` to parse the numbers to string and concat into a single string.

After that, using `$group` you can get the all values you need in the same array. And how you want set the `date` as KEY, is neccesary create fields `k` and `v` and parse again to string.

With the values together, using `$arrayToObject` you can cerate the schema you want `date: average` and use `$replaceRoot` to get only the values at top level.

To do this you need to add this query at the end of your aggregation.

```js
  {
    "$set": {
      "date": { "$dateFromString": { "dateString": {
            "$concat": [
              { "$toString": "$_id.dayOfMonth" }, "-",
              { "$toString": "$_id.month" }, "-",
              { "$toString": "$_id.year" }
            ] },
          "format": "%d-%m-%Y", "timezone": "Europe/Madrid"
        } } }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": null,
      "date": { "$push": { "k": { "$toString": "$date" }, "v": "$average" } }
    }
  },
  {
    "$replaceRoot": { "newRoot": { "$arrayToObject": "$date" } }
  }
```

This query add a new field called `date` like this:

```
"date": ISODate("2020-09-08T04:00:00Z")
```

I've used `Europe/Madrid` as `timezone` but you can choose you want to get your desired date.

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/LDTlBuPF_cv).

The output is:

```json
{
  "2020-09-07T22:00:00.000Z": 574998.153846154,
  "2020-09-08T22:00:00.000Z": 494217.606225681
}
```

Using `America/New_York` as timezone:

```
{
  "2020-09-08T04:00:00.000Z": 574998.153846154,
  "2020-09-09T04:00:00.000Z": 494217.606225681
}
```